# D3JS remove classes similar to JQuery removeClass()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a D3JS equivalent to Jquery's `removeClass()` ?

I want to remove all classes from a circle shape. I currently explicitly name and remove each class:

```
.on("click", function() {
  d3.select("#circle" + i)
    .classed("foo", false)
    .classed("bar", false) 
  }
```

I could test for foo, bar, and remove only when present, but I want to anticipate as-yet unnamed classes for removal and make my code more efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `d3.select("#circle" + i).attr("class", null)` to clear all classes in the selected elements.

Comment: You're still assigning a class with `attr("class", "")`. If you inspect the element, you'll see `<circle class></circle>`. However, if you do `.attr("class", null)`, you'll actually remove all classes, and you'll have `<circle></circle>`.

Comment: That's correct. I fixed my answer with your comment. Thanks!